# Quake Heaps with Heap-Ordered Trees instead of Tournament Trees

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

In the paper titled [*Quake Heaps:A Simple Alternative to Fibonacci Heaps*](https://tmc.web.engr.illinois.edu/heap_ianfest.pdf), by Timothy Chan He mentions that:

> The tournament trees require a linear number of extra nodes, but more space- efficient representations are possible where each element is stored in only one node. One option is to transform each tournament tree T into a heap-ordered, O(log n)-degree tree T ′: the children of x in T ′ are the right children of all the nodes storing x in T .
> [image: Image with a Heap Ordered Tree]

I was wondering, if we did make quake heap this way, how would we trigger the quake operation?